# Server side vs client side calendar

Tags: calendar, client-side, server-side

I want to create a calendar system, it is something like Google calendar allow users to post data but I have no idea I have to use a client or server side base on the calendar.

Any suggestion or tutorial about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you approach the question from the fact that you have to store, and visualize the data your users produce. To *show* the calendar, you will most likely need front end (client side) programming. To fetch and store the data, you will need a server side application. The upside is that if you get the server-side right, you can freely experiment with the client-side.